# zipWithIndex from 1 instead of 0

Tags: scala

If I have a list and zipWithIndex

```
val list = List('a', 'b', 'c')
val ziplist = List.zipWithIndex
// List[(int, int)] = List(('a', 0), ('b', 1), ('c', 2))
```

If I want to index from 1 instead of 0, is there a smarter way than my current:

```
val ziplist = List.zipWithIndex.map( ele => (ele._1, ele._2 + 1))
```

Hope you guys can help!

Described in the summarization

Answer (score 13):

You could use `LazyList.from(1)` to generate indexes:

```
List('a', 'b', 'c').zip(LazyList.from(1)) // List((a,1), (b,2), (c,3))
```

If you're using Scala older than **2.13**, you'd need to use `Stream` instead of `LazyList`:

```
List('a', 'b', 'c').zip(Stream.from(1)) // List((a,1), (b,2), (c,3))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
val ziplist = list zip (Stream from 1)
```